# Manga/webtoon where the protagonist has eyes that warn him of things using colours; his emotions were sent back to his younger self

Tags: story-identification, manga

A story about a male protagonist with special eyes that tells him if things are safe or not; green = safe.

Can’t remember if it’s a manga or webtoon. It starts with a male protagonist who was dying on a battlefield, the goddess took pity on him, sent his emotions back into his younger self, (not memories).

He had eyes that told him what is safe/good and what is dangerous/bad by using colors: green, orange, red. He used this to gamble, his eyes stopped working, borrowed money from his ex-girlfriend (who works in a cafe). Money got stolen while he took a nap by a river, the evil lady who stole his money tried to get him to enter a contract. From his future emotions, he knew he wanted an invitation instead.

This leads to a gathering of people in a school gym, their tasks are given. Invited people are given bags with tools. An oni busted out under the floor. People get killed. Stairways with gates, etc. This is considered the tutorial.

Points are given after, those points are needed to buy daily necessities. The protagonist had the highest points, given VIP room. Etc.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for *The Second Coming of Gluttony*

> He was an addict, a loser, a despicable human being. But, one fleeting dream that may not have been a dream at all reawakens his once-lost senses. Possessing a very unique ability, he would use that, and the dream, to forge his path in the world now known as the Lost Paradise.

**It start with a male protagonist who was dying on a battlefield, goddess took pity on him, sent his emotions back into younger self, (not memories).**
[image]

**He had eyes which told him what is safe/good and what is dangerous/bad by using colours:green, orange, red.**

[image]

Comment: Nice! How did you find it?

Comment: The webnovel can be found at https://www.novelupdates.com/series/the-second-coming-of-gluttony/ FWIW

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Most of the manga/webtoon story-identification I answer to are the ones I already read so if the description is enough to trigger my memory I go throught my bookmarks to find the corresponding manga.

Comment: Cool. Is it a site you can link to our one of the pirate manga sites? I know I caught some flak in the past for linking, or mentioning the name, of those.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Not sure 100% but I wouldn't be surprised if the ones I use are sailing under a black flag. Is there a list on the meta or somewhere else to know which sites are linkable or not?

Comment: I don't think so. Pretty much, if it's not by the company in question, or not licensed through something like Webtoons, it's probably not something we're supposed to be posting. No worries. Thanks for the talk.