# Looking for isekai manhwa beginning in a high-school's gym where peoples have to pass trials

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I forgot the real beginning of how the main character got involved, but he has to come to a meeting taking place in a gym with many random peoples (here for the same reason).
Some chosen peoples get stuff (the MC receives a gold bag) and the first test begins : simply get out of the gym but in limited time.
Once outside, the survivors must get into the high-school building, then inside they'll have to face new trials (escape monster, find items, etc) to finally reach the roof to complete the quest.

On the roof there is a portal to a new zone (seems like hotel's interior) for resting, where they can get quests (from a board) to improve their skills.

The survivors have months to improve before a war start...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [*Second Coming of Gluttony*](https://the-second-coming-of-gluttony.fandom.com/wiki/Seol_Jihu).

[This question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/iibml2/help_finding_manga/) was asking about the same property.

> So he meets a person who gives him a bag which does something (can't remember) he gets a gold bag. He is told to meet everyone in the gymhall since they will test people to see who gets to be isekai'd, mc already knows all this. (one ability from the bag is to be able to see danger/where is safe)

[image]

Comment: Wow, i see this title so many times but i don't recognize it...
Thanks, for the answer.

Comment: The same manhwa was also [asked](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/234475/manga-webtoon-where-the-protagonist-has-eyes-that-warn-him-of-things-using-colou/234502) in a different way